# Lagged Features

Tags: time-series, predictive-modeling, feature-selection, feature-engineering, data-science-model

Lets look for example, at the forecast the sales of a retail outlet.

If I understood the concept correctly, than a lagged feature would be the sales of a previous month t−1.

Would it make sense/is it common practice to create a lagged feature of a feature? For example number of customers and number of customers of a previous month t-1.

I'd be worried by doing so, that I'd give too much weight to unimportant features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagged values of features make sense with time series data, this is usually fundamental in time series analysis (because of autocorrelation). Now, whether you should include a lag or not of a feature is a different question, one that is very much data and model dependent, so we cannot answer this definitively.

One thing you might check is the aforementioned autocorrelation, if a feature has autocorrelation then maybe you should include lags, if however there is no autocorrelation then lags are probably useless.

Comment: Alright, so I'd have to look at the partial auto correlation plots for each feature as well?

Comment: @RomeroAzzalini It would help.